# Migrate MSSQL 2008R2 to 2012 (new hardware)

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Since hardware support for our server ends we are migrating to a new hardware and simultaneously upgrading MSSQL 2008R2 to MSSQL 2012. I searched a little bit and found some guides, but they all assume that I want to use new features of 2012. But we are actually only upgrading because the 2008R2 supports ends before the support of the new hardware and we don't want to upgrade later down the road.

Assuming I don't want any new features of 2012 is it as easy as restoring the 2008 databases on the new server? If that works, I guess it's not the recommended way, but is it bad? Does some have any good links, guides or other resources?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming I don't want any new features of 2012 is it as easy as
>   restoring the 2008 databases on the new server?

It is - plus setting trace flags for the server to force the old behavior of the query optimizer, I think.

> If that works, I guess it's not the recommended way,

Why not? It totally looks like the recommended way to me.

Comment: I would think that it is recommended to use the new features. But ok I couldn't find a whole lot of resources maybe because it's that easy and everyone is doing it that way. thanks

Comment: Then you misformulated. I was thinking about recommendation in terms of the upgrade approach (backup/restore). Using the new features is recommended - after making sure they are beneficial. Most programs will start not using them.

Comment: @TomTom Why the mention of the query optimizer? I don't believe anything changed from 2008r2 -> 2012. Are you thinking about the 2014 query optimizer redesign or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

First off, as [TomTom](https://serverfault.com/a/676946/218888) already stated, yes it is possible.
Using a backup / restore procedure is the proper way to upgrade your database.

However, you will still need to do some other actions.
You will need to [migrate the SQL server logins](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) to the new instance.
You will need to test if your app doesn't use [features that were removed.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/what-is-different-between-sql-server-versions-2008r2-and-2012)
Most notably here is the [object ID in the temp table](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/09/sql-server-11-denali-using-temp-tables.aspx).

However, don't start activating trace flags just yet.
The query optimizer has only been redesigned for [SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx).
In 2012 you won't see much difference, and are best to leave it as is.